# Find point on a path in 3d space, given initial and final position and starting velocity vector

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

Let's say I have an entity in 3d space and I know its position vector (x, y, z) and its velocity vector (so its orientation in space).

Starting from known point A I want to reach known point B in two steps:

a) turn, following a circular path with a known radius R, until point C

b) go straight from point C to final point B.

Speed (scalar value) is not important. Velocity (vector) is known, so I guess it should define the plane on which the circle resides, being tangent to it, together with the line between A and B...

I want to know how to find coordinates (x, y, z) for C and the velocity vector of the entity being there.

Comment: You don't say how many radians you should rotate through to reach point C.  There's no information about that point at all.

Comment: because it depends on the position of B, that is known but variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Update: see the working demo!](http://garethrees.org/2011/07/02/turning-circle/turning.html)

If I understand correctly, your situation (in the plane containing A, B and **v**) is as shown in the diagram below. The points A and B are given, as is the vector **v** and the distance *r*. You want to find the point C.

[image]

Well, let the vector **w** = (−v̂<sub>y</sub>, v̂<sub>x</sub>) be a unit vector perpendicular to **v**. Then O = A + *r* **w**.

Now, |C − O| = *r* and (C − B)·(C − O) = 0 (where · is the dot product). Combine these to get a quadratic equation, which you can solve to find the two possible positions for C. Then pick the one with the right sign for (C − B)×(C − O).

(There's a second choice for the centre of the circle, O = A − *r* **w**, representing turning clockwise instead of anticlockwise. This gives you another possibility for C. I guess you'll have to use some heuristic to decide which one you prefer: maybe the one with smallest ∠AOC.)

---

St0rM asks for help with doing this in 3D (see comments). That's easy! The plane containing A, B, and **v** has normal vector **n** = (A − B) × **v**. Let **u** = **n** × **v** be a vector perpendicular to both **n** and **v**, and let **w** = **û** (the unit vector in the direction of **u**).

You'll also need to take into account the constraint that C lies in the same plane as A: C·**n** = A.**n**, and "the right sign for (C − B)×(C − O)" becomes "the right sign for (C − B)×(C − O)·**n**".

---

Having trouble solving this system of equations?

Well, if (C − B)·(C − O) = 0, then (C − O + O − B)·(C − O) = 0, therefore (C − O)·(C − O) + (O − B)·(C − O) = 0, therefore C·(O − B) = O·(O − B) − *r*<sup>2</sup>.

You'll note that this is the equation for a plane, and so is C·**n** = A.**n**. Intersect these two planes ([see Wikipedia for details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29#Line_of_intersection_between_two_planes) — you can use the simpler solution since the planes are orthogonal and can easily be made orthonormal) to get the equation of a line on which C lies: C = H + λL, say, where L = **n**×(B − O). Then use (C − O)·(C − O) = *r*<sup>2</sup> to turn this into a quadratic equation in λ. You'll find that the quadratic equation simplifies quite a bit if you rewrite the equation of the line as C = H + λL + O so that occurrences of "− O" disappear.

[image]

Here's an implementation in Python using `numpy` to do the vector algebra. I'm sure you can figure out how to convert this to the language of your choice.

```py
import math
from numpy import cross, dot
from numpy.linalg import norm

def unit(v):
    """Return a unit vector in the same direction as v."""
    return v / norm(v)

def turnpoints(A, B, v, r):
    """Generate possible turning instructions for a path from A to B
that starts out in direction v, turns through part of a circle of radius
r until it reaches a point C (to be determined), then heads straight for
B. Return each instruction in the form (sense, C) where sense is -1 for
clockwise and +1 for anticlockwise."""
    n = unit(cross(A - B, v))   # Unit normal to plane containing A, B, v.
    w = unit(cross(n, v))       # Unit normal to v lying in that plane.
    for sense in (-1, +1):      # Turn clockwise or anticlockwise?
        O = A + sense * r * w   # Centre of turning circle.
        BB = B - O
        m = unit(BB)
        # C lies on the line H + l*L + O
        H = dot(A, n) * n + (r**2 / norm(BB)) * m
        L = cross(n, m)
        # |C - O| = r**2 gives quadratic eqn in l with coefficients a=1, b=0, c.
        c = dot(H, H) - r**2
        disc = - 4 * c          # Discriminant of quadratic eqn.
        if disc < 0:
            continue            # No tangents (B inside circle).
        elif disc == 0:         # One tangent (B on circle).
            C = H + O
            yield (sense, C)
        else:                   # Two tangents (B outside circle)
            for sign in (-1, +1):
                l = sign * math.sqrt(disc) / 2
                C = H + l * L + O
                # Only one choice for C is correct (the other involves
                # reversing direction).
                if dot(cross(C - B, C - O), n) * sense > 0:
                    yield (sense, C)
```

Comment: You might want to mention that there are two choices for O (one or both may work depending on A,B,r).

Comment: @brainjam: Sure. (Both choices for O work, it's just that in one case you have to turn further than the other.)

Comment: @Gareth, that's the case for your diagram, I can draw other diagrams for which only one choice works.  For example A and B close together relative to r.

Comment: @brainjam, Oh yes, I see: if B is inside one of the turning circles, that forces you to turn the other way. (This will show up as an unsolvable quadratic equation.)

Comment: It's almost perfect... How to find w in 3d, hovewere ? If I understand correctly, Vx and Vy in your definition refer to x and y on the plane defined  by A-B and v, but my math is not strong enough to understand how :-)

Comment: Is:
 C·n = A·n 
...really true ? C and A are not parallel, am I missing something ? Shouldn't be something like: 
 (C-A)·n = (C-O)·n 
...or even:
 (C-A)·(C-O) = 0 
?

Comment: If n is a vector normal to a plane, then for any two points P and Q in the plane, P·n = Q·n. Quick proof: (P − Q) is perpendicular to n, therefore (P − Q)·n = 0, therefore P·n = Q·n.

Comment: You're welcome. I made a demo too: http://garethrees.org/2011/07/02/turning-circle/turning.html

Answer (score 1):

Woo, this is interesting.

1. Find the plane that points A, B, and the entity's velocity exist on. Everything will happen on this plane, so now you can think of the problem as 2D, though the math will still be 3D.
2. Find the center point of the circle the entity will be traveling along on the plane. This center point will be perpendicular to the entity's velocity, at a distance of R.  There will actually be 2 different places you could place the circle, you'll need to choose based on which is closer to B.
3. Find the two lines from B that are tangential to the circle. The points where these lines touch the circle are your two possibilities for C. Determine which point will allow your entity to hit B when it reaches it and leaves the circle (the other point will bring the entity in exactly the opposite direction).

From this, you should be able to get the position of C, and I'm fairly certain that, if the entity doesn't change speed, the vector should just be the unit vector from C to B times the magnitude of the original velocity vector.

Any or all of this could be wrong. I'm just figuring this from doodling on a piece of paper.

Comment: +1: sounds about right, according to my doodles on a piece of paper.  Now you just have to nail down the formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is a shorter version. You could compute C from:

H = O + (r^2)/|BB|)*m

C = H + l*(sqrt(r^2 - |HO|^2))     //this simply applies Pytagora to find out HC magnitude

as a proof of concept:

```
   cml::vector3f A( 4, 3, 2);
   cml::vector3f B( 1, 5, 0);

   cml::vector3f v( 1, 0, 0);
   float r = 1.4142;

   cml::vector3f n = cml::cross((A-B),v);
   n.normalize();
   cout << "n: " << n << endl;

   cml::vector3f w = cml::cross(n,v);
   w.normalize();
   cout << "w: " << w << endl;

   cml::vector3f O = A + r*w;
   cout << "O: " << O << endl;

   cml::vector3f m = B-O;
   m.normalize();
   cout << "m: " << m << endl;

   cml::vector3f OB = B - O;
   cml::vector3f H = O + m * ( pow(r,2) / OB.length() );
   cout << "H: " << H << endl;

   cml::vector3f l = cml::cross(m,n);;
   l.normalize();
   cout << "l: " << l << endl;

   cml::vector3f OH = H - O;
   cml::vector3f C = H + l * ( sqrt( pow(r,2)-pow(OH.length(),2) ) );
   cout << "C: " << C << endl;
```

Comment: Nice one, it's pretty shorter and simpler.

Comment: ... but once you've added the code for turning in both directions, for checking for non-solutions, and for picking the correct tangent, then you'll find it's essentially the same.